# Join two table with department wise maximum salary

Tags: sql

Department wise maximum salary in a table it's working:

```
select * from employee where (emp_dept, emp_sal) 
in (select emp_dept, max(emp_sal) from employee group by emp_dept);
```

but my concern is : i want emp_id, emp_name, emp_sal, emp_dept column with department wise maximnum salary

```
customer table : cust_id, cust_name, emp_id
employee table : emp_id, emp_name, emp_sal, emp_dep
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want :

```
select e.emp_id, e.emp_name, e.emp_sal, e.emp_dept
from employee e
where e.emp_sal = (select max(e1.emp_sal) from employee e1 where e1.emp_dept = e.emp_dept);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all the records from the employee table with the maximum salary added, then you could use something like:

```
Select e.emp_id, e.emp_name, e.emp_sal, e.emp_dept, d.max_salary
from employee e
left join 
(select emp_dept,max(emp_sal) as max_salary
 from employee
 group by emp_dept) d
ON e.emp_dept=d.emp_dept
```

The sub query calculates the maximum salary for each department and then using the left join you can get it into the final table.

If you want the employee details of the employee with the maximum salary, then:

```
Select e.emp_id, e.emp_name, e.emp_sal, e.emp_dept, d.max_salary
from employee e
inner join 
(select emp_dept,max(emp_sal) as max_salary
 from employee
 group by emp_dept) d
ON e.emp_dept=d.emp_dept and e.emp_sal=d.max_salary
```

In this case the join is based on the salary component as well, thereby returning only the employees with the maximum salary. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a window function:

```
select e.*,
       max(emp_sal) over (partition by emp_dept) as dept_max_sal
from employee ;
```